# Script dentro de input text

Tags: php, javascript

Eu tenho um rand que gera números de 0 a 5, queria que ao clicar em um botão ele gere o número dentro do input text. Eu fiz de uma forma porém ao clicar no botão gerar o número é gerado fora do input, segue o código:

```html
<?php
session_start();
if(!empty($_SESSION['email'])){
 
}else{
 echo"<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('ArÃŠa Restrita.');
    window.location.href='/bolao/index.php';</script>";
}
$nome=$_SESSION['nome'];

$placarc = substr(mt_rand (0,5),0,1); //gera números de para time casa 0 a 5
$placarf = substr(mt_rand (0,5),0,1); //gera números de para time fora 0 a 5
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel='stylesheet' href='//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css'/>
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
 <!-- As 3 meta tags acima *devem* vir em primeiro lugar dentro do `head`; qualquer outro conteÃēdo deve vir *apÃŗs* essas tags -->
    <title>Lance Web</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- HTML5 shim e Respond.js para suporte no IE8 de elementos HTML5 e media queries -->
    <!-- ALERTA: Respond.js nÃŖo funciona se vocÃĒ visualizar uma pÃĄgina file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
 <style type="text/css">
  /*Aqui deixa a imagem de fundo responsiva*/
  body{ 
   background: url(../img/principal.png) no-repeat center center fixed; 
   -webkit-background-size: cover;
   -moz-background-size: cover;
   -o-background-size: cover;
   background-size: cover;
  }
  
  #font{
   color:black;
   font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
   font-size: 20px;
   
  }
  
  #fonttitulo{
   color:black;
   font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
   font-size: 24px;
   
  }
  
  .img-responsive {
   max-width:250px;
   max-height:150px;
   width: auto;
   height: auto;
   
  }
  
    
 </style>
 
 <!-- Aqui começa o script para gerar um placar para o time casa -->
 <script>
  function myFunction(){
   document.getElementById("casa").innerHTML = <?php echo $placarc; ?>;
  }
 </script>
 
 <!-- Aqui começa o script para gerar um placar para o time fora -->
 <script>
  function myFunction2(){
   document.getElementById("fora").innerHTML = <?php echo $placarf; ?>;
  }
 </script>
</head>
<body>
<!--------------------------------------------------------- nav e o menu -------------------------------------------------------------------> 
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    
 <!-- Aqui e como ira aparece em um telefone -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <!-- Aqui no span, sÃŖo os 3 pontos ao abrir em um telefone -->
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">Voltar</a>
 </div>

    <!-- Aqui se edita a parte do saldo -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
   <li class=""><a href="partidas.php">Cadastrar Partidas<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
   <li class=""><a href="editarpartidas.php">Editar Partidas<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
  </ul>
      
      <!-- Aqui se edita a parte do sair -->  
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
     <li><a href="sair.php"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
        
    </div><!-- fim da div collapse, ela faz com que abra um menu ao aumentar o site -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>

<!------------------------------------------------- Aqui começa o formulario de cadastrar os placares -------------------------------------> 
 <form class="form-group" action="" method="post">
  <div class="container" align="center" >
   <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4"><br><br>
    <label id="font">Time Casa</label>
     <select class="form-control" name="timecasa" required>
       <option selected></option>
       <option value="Atletico-go">Atlético-GO</option>
       <option value="Atletico-mg">Atlético-MG</option>
       <option value="Atletico-pr">Atlético-PR</option>
       <option value="Avai">Avaí</option>
       <option value="Bahia">Bahia</option>
       <option value="Botafogo">Botafogo</option>
       <option value="Corinthians">Corinthians</option>
       <option value="Coritiba">Coritiba</option>
       <option value="Cruzeiro">Cruzeiro</option>
       <option value="Chapecoense">Chapecoense</option>
     </select><br>
    
    <label id="font">Placar time Casa</label> 
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-3 col-xs-3" id="casa">
       <input class="form-control" type="text" name="placarcasa" maxlength="1" value="" style="text-align: center;" required></div>
      <div class="col-xs-4">
       <input class="btn btn-success submit-botao" type="submit" value="Gerar" onclick="myFunction()">
      </div>
     </div><hr><br><!-- Fim div row placar casa-->
     
    <label id="font">Time Fora</label>
     <select class="form-control" name="timefora" required>
      <option selected></option>
      <option value="Flamengo">Flamengo</option>
      <option value="Fluminense">Fluminense</option>
      <option value="Gremio">Grêmio</option>
      <option value="Palmeiras">Palmeiras</option>
      <option value="Ponte preta">Ponte Preta</option>
      <option value="Santos">Santos</option>
      <option value="Sao paulo">São Paulo</option>
      <option value="Sport">Sport</option>
      <option value="Vasco">Vasco</option>
      <option value="Vitoria">Vitória</option>
    </select><br>
    
    <label id="font">Placar time fora</label> 
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-3 col-xs-3" id="fora">
       <input class="form-control" type="int" name="placarfora" maxlength="1" value="" style="text-align: center;" required></div>
      <div class="col-xs-4">
       <input class="btn btn-success submit-botao" type="submit" value="Gerar" onclick="myFunction2()">
      </div>
     </div><hr><br><!-- Fim div row placar fora-->
     
     <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1"> 
      <a href="index.php"><input class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" type="button" value="Cancelar"></a>
     </div>
   
     <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1">
      <input class="btn btn-info btn-lg submit-botao" type="submit" value="Cadastrar" name="btnCadastrar">
     </div>
    
   </div><!-- Fim div mover-->
   
  </div><!-- Fim div container -->
  
 </form><!-- Fim formulario-->
  
 </div><!-- Fim Div row-->
 
 </div><!-- Fim Div container-->

<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js'></script>
<script src='//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No seu input você pode colocar um `id`

```
<input id="placar-c" class="form-control" type="text" name="placarcasa" maxlength="1" value="" style="text-align: center;" required />
```

E na sua função javascript você seta o valor no elemento

```
function myFunction(){
    document.getElementById("placar-c").value = <?php echo $placarc; ?>;
}
```

Comment: Valeu, deu certo.

Comment: @pherb sinalize a resposta como "correta" marcando um V verde. Isso estimula os usuários do SO a continuarem respondendo perguntas.